# parent().remove is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

I have a problem with deleting the parent on a click on .icon-trash

```
<div class="ui-wrapper ui-draggable">
  <img id="link1" class="decor ui-resizable" src="http://i.imgur.com/nYkdOne.png">
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
  <img class="icon-layer-up icon-on-img" src="" style="z-index: 1;">
  <img class="icon-layer-down icon-on-img" src="" style="z-index: 1;">
  <img class="icon-trash icon-on-img" src="" style="z-index: 1;">
  <img class="icon-copy-el icon-on-img" src="" style="z-index: 1;">
</div>
```

My js code is deliting only elements with a class .icon-on-img

```
$(document).on('click', '.icon-trash', function() {  
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

How can I remove everything by clicking on .icon-trash element?

Comment: Does the code actually get called?

Comment: Are you getting any error? As I tried your code and it is working fine in JsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/SgDs6/

Comment: Woah, look at all these answers trying to fix what's not broken..

Comment: I think I might have some problem with event propagation

Comment: Which problem? That code works fine. Are you implying your browser has an issue with its implementation of event bubbling? That would be very surprising.

Answer (score 0):

> try this

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".icon-trash").on("click", function () {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

working example here: (click on the orange box) http://jsfiddle.net/cpEff/

just added the class '.ui-wrapper'  from your parent div to your jQuery

```
$(document).on('click', '.icon-trash', function() {  
  $(this).parent('.ui-wrapper').remove();
});
```

Comment: @mattias yep just seen it and update the answer with a question

Comment: @lipenco sorry it also works without the class in .parent()

are you sure you included jQuery?

Answer (score -1):

The following code should work:

```
$('.icon-trash').on('click', function() {  
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: I am assuming op method is used for delegation. Your above answer will not provide this

Comment: Please stick to English.

Answer (score -1):

Use body on the event

```
$('body').on('click', '.icon-trash', function() {  
    $(this).parent().remove();
 });
```

working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HdMNY/